# Why is cypress running old code instead of updated?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm working on cypress (tried 8.0.0, 8.7.0, 7.7.0) to write a simple e2e tests that fill a form.

Yesterday I updated a `.click()` to `.click({ multiple: true })`, then removed it.
Since then, the code executed is the old one, regardless of the modifications made to my test

Error comes from click with multiple: true
[image]

My test (no occurence of "multiple"):

```
const moment = require('moment');

const destinationElements = 'elem de ci';
const orderedVolume = '100';
const deliveryFrequency = '25';
const deliveryTime = '23:00';
const additionalInfo = 'réalisé via cypress';

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', err => {
  return false;
});

describe('Create concrete order', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  it('should create a concrete order', () => {
    cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/home');

    cy.get('[data-testid=createOrderLink] button').click();

    // Fill form

    const tomorrowDate = moment()
      .add(1, 'days')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    cy.get('input[data-test-id=deliveryDate]').click();
    cy.get(`td[title=${tomorrowDate}]`)
      .click()
      .wait(10);

    cy.fillInput('orderedVolume', orderedVolume);
    cy.fillInput('deliveryFrequency', deliveryFrequency);
    cy.fillInput('deliveryTime', deliveryTime);
    cy.fillInput('destinationElements', destinationElements);

    cy.get('button[data-test-id=create-order-button]').click();

    cy.get('tbody tr:last-child td:nth-child(5)').should(
      'have.text',
      destinationElements,
    );
  });
});
```

Edit: It seems that the problem is the cache

When i clear the can on chromium and re-run the test, its working.

[image]

Comment: Close your test runner and start again. I have faced these issue as well, sometimes the changes I made was not reflected in the test run.

Comment: I just edited, looks like its a cache issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache issues can happen when service workers are caching your files in a local environment, even if the affected code is some Cypress code. Service workers can mess with Webpack.